# jQuery fade in elements on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I`m trying make a jquery code ho fadeIn elemens on scroll down with slice function.
There is my code

```
var count = jQuery('#am-container a').size();
var lastScroll = 0;

jQuery('#show').text(count);
jQuery('#am-container a').hide();
jQuery('#am-container a').slice(0, 16).fadeIn(500);

jQuery(window).scroll(function(event){
    var st = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScroll){
        jQuery("#am-container a").slice(16, count).fadeIn(500);
    }
    lastScroll = st;
});
```

16 elements appear as they should be, but when scroll down, nothing happens!
maybe slice() isn`t the best way? Please help and sorry for bad English

Comment: Hey aidron, can you expand on what your issue actually is? Are you getting an error? Is `fadeIn` actually getting called? etc.

Comment: Hey Andrew, no, there is no errors when in scroll effect i use alert(); it`s works, but when  using the fadeIn it`s not working, i think the code is wrong. Right now i have 141 a elements and inside there is img element. 16 a elements ar visible and others are hidden, how can i on scroll show next 16 elements and after again 16 elements untill hidden elements is ended?

Comment: Are you certain that `count` is correctly set? The only things that look likely to be wrong are `count` being set to a number smaller than 16 (and therefore slicing nothing) and the fact that you are using `scroll` which will be called many many times.

Comment: Also, your code isn't setup to show the next 16, it is setup to show all elements starting with the 16th every time the window is scrolled.

Comment: And how can i set up to show next 16? http://jsfiddle.net/6zb81uLt/